# Should non-secure cookies be sent over HTTPS?

Tags: cookies

I'm writing code to determine if a given cookie should be set on requests for a given URL and am currently considering the [secure attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie).

I understand that a cookie marked as secure must be sent over HTTPS and must not be sent over HTTP.

I'm not clear on whether a cookie that is not explicitly marked as secure can be sent over HTTPS.

Should cookies not marked as secure be sent over HTTPS?

Or, in other words, can you complete the following table?

```
Secure attribute value | Request URL scheme | Allow cookie to be set?
=====================================================================
 true                  | HTTPS              | Yes
 true                  | HTTP               | No
 false (or not set)    | HTTPS              | ?
 false (or not set)    | HTTP               | Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-secure cookies can be sent over HTTPS. The secure flag is simply a way of instructing browsers to not send them across HTTP. They do not have to honour this, although I think all major browsers do.

They will happily send a non-secure cookie across HTTP though.

Comment: Cool, this was my assumption but I couldn't find it defined in an RFC (such as 6265 which generally covers cookie matters very well).

Comment: Hmm not sure about references, this is the behaviour I've observed. Maybe someone else can point to the relevant docs.